# Как получить все вхождения, заключенные в круглые скобки

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение прмерно такого плана: `/^(\s\d\s(\d+,\d+))+/`
Нужно получить значения во вложенных скобках, т.е. `$2`, но таких вхождений в строке может быть несколько в `$2` соранится лишь последнее, `$3`, `$4` и др. пустые.

Comment: В приведенном шаблоне нет третьей, четвертой и др. групп. Буфер для каждой захватывающей подмаски существует только в .NET ([CaptureCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capturecollection.item%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396))

Comment: Одни скобки - одна переменная. Так что простейший ответ - никак. Надо искать другие пути, которые зависят от того языка в котором вы эту регулярку используете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для именно такой регулярки ответ очевиден: (это ведь perl?)

```
my @groups = split (/\s\d\s/, $incominc_string);
foreach (@groups) {
    if (/(\d+),(\d+)/) {
        print "$1 - $2\n";
    }
}
```

для надежности:

```
my @groups = grep { /^\d+,\d+$/ } split(/\s\d\s/, $incoming_string);
```

А так выше в комментариях все правильно написали - одни скобки == одна переменная и изменить это поведение (ЕМНИП) нельзя.